# Passing weak_ptr by reference to lambda

Tags: c++

I observe an undefined behavior at runtime on my program and I suspect it might have caused by the weak_ptr.

The send function of socket get called but it can't map the socket, but if I remove Lambdas it can map the socket.

The worker function was synchronous before and had no issues, but  it cause undefined behavior now after adding Lambdas into worker function.

Is this really unsafe? if so, what should I use instead?

```
// Global Socket
std::shared_ptr<s::Channel> gSocket;

void worker(std::weak_ptr<s::Channel> socket)
{
    auto &request = requests.emplace_back();

    request.onMessage([&](std::string data) {
        if (auto channel = socket.lock())
        {
            channel->send(data);
        }
    })

    request.onError([&](std::string data) {
        if (auto channel = socket.lock())
        {
            channel->send(data);
        }
    })
}

int main() {
    broker->onInit([&]() {
        // Shared PTR
        gSocket = createConnection();

        gSocket->onOpen([&, wS = make_weak_ptr(gSocket)]() {
            if (auto c = wS.lock())
            {
                worker(c);
            }
        });
    })

    broker.init();
}
```

Comment: It looks like `worker` returns after setting two callbacks. Is it *really* a shock that a reference to a local variable becomes dangling?

Comment: what do you mean when you say "undefined behavior"? I suppose what you actually mean is that you get unexpected output (because if you knew that it is ub not just some logic error, you would also know already where it is)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Undefined behavior means the send fails, but send pass if I take it out of scope. I just want to confirm whether this caused by weak_ptr

Comment: please do not call it "undefined behavior" (yet), that terms has a well defined meaning. Instead you should desribe what you see and what you expected instead

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 That's what I see. It's undefined and didn't happen before...

Comment: @StoryTeller - Unslander Monica The code compiles however, but I don't understand what you mean but yes I suspected it become invalid after out of scope..

Comment: `std::weak_ptr<s::Channel> socket` is a local variable, it is destroyed after the function returns. When the callback is called later, it is referring to a non-existent weak_ptr instance.

Comment: not sure if you get my point. What you see is a bug in your program. Whether this is due to some mistake, or if it really is due to [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) in your code, you don't know yet. Dereferencing a nullptr actually is undefined, but before we know that your code really has UB, it is misleading to call it "undefined"

Comment: @jeffbRTC - "The code compiles however" You say that as if it's an indication of it being bug free.

Comment: in any case, "it has undefined behavior" is not a sufficient description of the issue. What happens when you run the program and what should happen instead? Please add that information to the question

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I was expecting compiler to caught this for me but not high hopes just saying in case

Comment: @rustyx What would be your solution to keep the weak ptr alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments

> `std::weak_ptr<s::Channel>` socket is a local variable, it is destroyed after the function returns. When the callback is called later, it is referring to a non-existent weak_ptr instance.

You can fix it by capturing `socket` by value:

```
void worker(std::weak_ptr<s::Channel> socket)
{
    auto &request = requests.emplace_back();

    request.onMessage([socket, &request](std::string data) {
        if (auto channel = socket.lock())
        {
            channel->send(data);
        }
    })

    request.onError([socket, &request](std::string data) {
        if (auto channel = socket.lock())
        {
            channel->send(data);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Also note that `data` could be a `std::string const&`

Comment: but I also need to capture request  by reference. In that case,  which notation should I use?